# Why is the Repository code block executing after the init. of the Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, repository

I am trying to fetch a list of parks from my Repository so that I can pass them to my RecyclerView Adapter, and show each parks information(name, type & state) in a ViewHolder.

### The Problem

The code to initialize the Adapter is executing before the code to fetch the List of parks.

### The Code

```
Repository.getParks(new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processParks(List<Park> parks) {
                parksList = parks;
                
            }
        });


        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewParksList);
        //passing the parksList retrieved into the Adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ParkListAdapter(parksList));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

### How I know this is happening

The code shown above actually doesn't work as it gives a null pointer exception. However, when I logged the array list's size, it showed 100. Thus, I moved the code block for the RecyclerView initialization inside the getParks method(after I fetched the list of parks), and everything began working fine.

### The Question

Why is this behavior occurring (the RecyclerView/adapter initialization before the fetching of the list of parks)?

Comment: `Repository.getParks` is an Asynchronous call hence its running on separate thread  . You need set data in side `processParks` to RV .

Comment: Hi, thanks. I see. But in my getParks() method it takes in the AsyncReponse as a callback: public static void getParks(final AsyncResponse callback){}. In that method, at the very end: I invoke processParks(): if(callback != null){
                        callback.processParks(parkList);
                    }. So shouldn't this mean that the code in getParks() gets executed, and then the callback gets invoked?

Comment: That exactly what it means . but rest of the code won't wait for it because it running on Main thread .

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you.